# No SQL database joins and grouping

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a MongoDB collection with documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c153f1"),
    "transid" : 1,
    "acct" : "acct1",
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "Fees",
    "amount" : 103
}
```

In my app I want to show users a list of all available categories from a set list and also give them the option to add new categories.  These would show up in a drop down.  My question is how do I store the distinct list of categories because they may not actually be assigned to a transaction.

Should I have a category collection that populates my dropdown?

Also when I am pulling a list of all my transactions by category, how do I also include categories that do not have any transactions?

Answer (score 0):

You can have them in separate collection, then in this case you need to fire a aggregate $lookup query to fetch data from two different collections. Refer [here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

The other option is to keep it in the same collection not having the other details like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583f6e6d14c8042dd7c153e1"),
    "transdate" : ISODate("2012-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"),
    "category" : "Fees"
}
```

Then to fetch category you can fire a distinct query like

> db.runCommand( { distinct: "collectionName", key: "category" } )

My preference will be to go with the second approach. The first one is a traditional RDBMS approach where there is a need to maintain two collection and do a lookup which is expensive. 
The scenario doesn't seems to be requiring need to have a extra overhead, but the choice is simply yours.